# textual data or text data?

Tags: morphology

What is the correct form in the following example?

*"The scientist is an expert at handling **text data**"*

or

*"The scientist is an expert at handling **textual data**"*

Are there cases were the former and/or the latter form is a better option?

Comment: Does the data relate to a text or is it simply in the form of text?

Comment: Which area of study? The term textual data is widely used in some fields, as [a Google search shows](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22textual+data%22), with various connotations, including [qualitative reserach](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/collecting-qualitative-data/textual-data-collection/6A6EC8922E13C127D9EAA41AE431A2F8) and [databases for corpora research in linguistics](https://guides.library.ualberta.ca/data/text). On the other hand I can see "text data" being used in some contexts such as [text data mining](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/text-mining).

Comment: It's possible that non-historical dictionaries indicate the default sense of 'textual' (pertaining to a  specific text? to textual material in general); this should be at least explored.

Comment: The data is in the form of text and may relate to any subject such science, arts, politics etc.

The area of study is sentiment analysis or other natural language processing tasks.

Comment: I would prefer: *The data scientist is an expert in NLP.* Natural Language Processing covers all manner of text such as written works, Twitter feeds, and newspaper corpus.

Comment: Probably *text data*.

Answer (score 1):

> According to [Vocabulary.com - textual (dictionarY)](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/textual)
>
> > Anything textual has to do with writing. A textual analysis, comparison, or interpretation, has something to do with what is in a particular piece of writing (or text). Textual comes from the Latin word textualis, the adjective form of textus, ("text").

> According to [Wikidiff - textual vs text](https://wikidiff.com/textual/text):
>
> > Textual is a derived term of text.
> > As a adjective textual is of, or pertaining to text.
> > As a noun text is a consisting of multiple glyphs, characters, symbols or sentences.
> > As a verb text is to send a text message to; to transmit text using the short message service (sms), or a similar service, between communications devices, particularly mobile phones

In your sentence it is hard to tell what the scientist is actually good at, so that cannot be answered at the moment.